# c++ private class inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Please excuse my English skills; as I'm not a native speaker.

i got this code from my college textbook and im having trouble understanding it for hours...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class base{
    int a;
protected:
    void seta(int a){this->a=a;}
public:
    void showa(){cout<<a;}
};

class derived: private base{
    int b;
protected:
    void setb(int b){this->b=b;}
public:
    void showb(){
        seta(5); //1
        showa(); //2
        cout<<b;
    }
};

class grandderived: private derived{
    int c;
protected:
    void setab(int x){
        seta(x); //3
        showa(); //4
        setb(x); //5
    }
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

here are my understandings so far:

class `derived` inherits class `base` as private, so everything inside class base are private. afaik private members cannot be accessed from subclasses.
so, number 1, 2 wont work.
class `grandderived` also inherits class `derived` as private, therefore 3,4, and 5 will also not work for the same reason.

but the answer tells me only number 3 and 4 wont work, and others will work.
i compiled it and yes it tells me the same.

am i misunderstanding something about how the inheritance works, or are there other things that i dont know of?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what's happening:

1. The `base` class declared `seta` and `showa` as protected and public. This means they are accessible to subclasses.
2. `derived` inherits from `base`. This means it has access to everything protected and public from `base`, which includes `seta` and `showa`. The fact that it privately inherits `base` means that inherited members will be marked as private, and thus cannot be accessed in classes subclassing `derived` (i.e. `grandderived`).
3. This same pattern occurs between `derived` and `grandderived`.

Therefore: `derived` can access the methods from `base`, and `grandderived` can access the methods from `derived`, but NOT `base`.

Answer (score 1):

You're close.

`grandderived` inherits from `derived` and marks it as private.  However, this means that the methods that has inherited from `derived` will not be accessible from classes inheriting from `grandderived`.  In the same way, `derived` inherits from `base`, marking it as private.

The effect is that `grandderived` *can* access the methods of `derived` but not `base`.

Answer (score 1):

`derived` class inherits `base` class privately, which means all public and protected members of the `base` class becomes **private** in the derived class.

Even though it is a private inheritance, `private` can access to all protected and public members of `base`. So number 1 and 2 work.

`base::seta` is a protected member in base, it becomes private in `derived`'s scope. `grandderived` can't access `derived`'s private members, therefore number 3 and 4 won't work.

`derived::setb`, number 5, works as it is declared protected in class `derived`. Although it becomes private in the scope of `grandderived`, it is accessible from itself. It can't be inherited further.

Answer (score 0):

Just as you can access your `private` members but others cannot, you can access your `private` base classes but others cannot. This is why class `derived` can access `base::seta` but class `gradderived` can't.

The main effect `private` inheritance has is that objects of the derived type can't be cast (from outside the class) to the base class type.